# How to know the previous page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two different pages, but both goes to the same page `X`.
When I get to the page `X`, is possible to know what was the last page? I mean, what was the page that redirected to the page `X`.

e.g: I'm on `page1.aspx` and I have a button that redirect to `bonus.aspx`, but I also have
`page2.aspx` that has another button but also redirect to `bonus.aspx`. Is possible to know what was the page that redirected to `bonus.aspx`? What was the last page ?

I need to know it because i'll modify the content of `bonus.aspx` according to the previous page.

I just want to do something like this:

```
protected void bonus_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if(PreviousPage.Name == "page1.aspx")
         {
           //Do Something
         }
     else if(PreviousPage.Name == "page2.aspx")
         {
            //Do Other Things
         }
  }
```

Obs: I need to use it on a `button_OnClick="" Event`

Comment: There`s a `PreviousPage` property which is not `null` if you'd use `Server.Transfer` instead of `Response.Redirect`. Then you could also access all controls and their `ViewState` of the last page.

Comment: @TimSchmelter hmm... I'll search for some documentation about it. Is it easy ?

Comment: You could pass the previous page as a Query String Paramater and store as a hidden field. This previous page issue can quickly become a very nasty problem if not solved simply.

Comment: @Ghaleon: Documentation of the `PreviousPage` property? I would start with [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).

Answer (score 6):

```
protected void bonus_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string previousPage = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath;

    if (previousPage == "/page1.aspx")
    {
        //Do Something
    }
    else if (previousPage == "/page2.aspx")
    {
        //Do Other Things
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually didnt work... It returns me the current page I need the previous =s . I have a "Return" button, when I click on it, the string `referrer` gets the current page as value. So it  will never get into an `if`... How Could I do that ? Thanks

Comment: @Ghaleon Can you post the code from `page1.aspx` and `page2.aspx` responsible for the redirection to `bonus.aspx`?

Answer (score 6):

In the `Page_Load` function:

```
   if(!Page.IsPostback)
   {
     var referrer = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
   }
```

Update:
The following method call will return you in a format similar to "/Page1.aspx".

```
var referrer = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath
```

Comment: Worked... But it gives me the whole URL right ? Do you know a way to get only the name of the page ? like: `page1.aspx` ? Thanks !

Comment: then you need to use segments property. please refer to : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hey @daryal. The `segments property` worked just perfect !! And to solve the problem I stored the value on a label with `Visible=False` may this become a problem in the future ?

Comment: @Ghaleon you can store the value in ViewState or session also instead of saving in a label. I may advise you to go with ViewState: ViewState["Url"] = "asdqwe".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the UrlRefferer Property. More Info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx

Comment: the problem is... I need to use it on a button, when I click on the button the Requested page becomes the current page... I dont know what to do =s